# How can i retrieve a field value from a specific document in firestore using flutter?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This is the code i have written but facing some error like "cant use String in getOptions()"

```
                totalClasses = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection('tutors')
                    .doc(uid)
                    .get("TotalClassesTook")
                    .then((value) {
                  return value.data();
                });
```

[How to retrieve the TotalClassesTook field value from this doc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MdQet.png)
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtrLL.png)

Comment: Where in your code are you using `getOptions` ?

Comment: @NisanthReddy ,Now I have attached the error image please check it once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While using the `FirebaseFirestore.instance` to get your data, the `.get()` is for specifying the `GetOptions` with feature like `cache`.

But that is not what you require.

Use it like this,

```
totalClasses = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
    .collection('tutors')
    .doc(uid)
    .get()
    .then((value) {
       return value.data()['TotalClassesTook']; // Access your after your get the data
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

For me the Nishanth's answer was not working, so this one worked for me.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('tutors')
  .doc(uid)
  .get()
  .then((value) {
   print(value.get('TotalClassesTook')); 
 });
```

Or this:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('tutors')
  .doc(uid)
  .get()
  .then((value) {
Map data = value.data() as Map;
   print(data['TotalClassesTook']); 
 });
```

Both of them worked for me.